# How to read text via javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a small module. I have uploaded `.html` file and read that file via `textContent`. Now I have written a small function for all links. Function name is `linkGenerate()`. But that function can't read the uploaded text. Function works fine if i use `innerHTML`. But I don't want to use it. I want to see the uploaded file as a text format so that I can save it back. can anyone tell me how can i read uploaded file and select all links from the that file.

Here is the snippet

```js
function linkGenerate() {
 let links = result.getElementsByTagName('a').textContent;
  // let links = result.getElementsByTagName('a');
  // let links = result.querySelectorAll("[href]");
 for(let link of links)
 {
  let curhref = link.href;
  if(curhref.indexOf('http') > -1)
  {
      link.href = curhref.replace(/(\?|&)elqTrackId=[a-z0-9]+(&elqTrack=true)?/, '');
      if(link.href.indexOf('ea=') > -1)
      {
        link.href += '&utm_source=iconnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&emailId={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&codsId={{Account.CODS_External_Id__c}}&utm_term=';
      }
      else
      {
        link.href += '?utm_source=iconnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&emailId={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&codsId={{Account.CODS_External_Id__c}}&utm_term=';
      }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Zip</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS
  ==================== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom Stylesheet 
    ===================== -->

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">test</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col">

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
          </div>
          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" onchange="return fileValidation()">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Output Div -->
        <div id="result" contenteditable="true"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <!-- Custom Script 
    ================ -->
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your wish. What you are doing now seems to be what you should do. What do you mean by `But I don't want to use it. I want to see the uploaded file as a text format so that I can save it back` What do you need to modify before saving that you cannot do by treating the file as HTML?

Comment: What is  `result`?

Comment: I wanted to get all links from the uploaded file and  wanted to replace with new links

Comment: `result` is the div where I have shown the uploaded file @trincot

Comment: Can you embed a snippet (not a link to another site please) that defines that `result` variable and that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add some more code

Comment: Can you please check the post now, I have updated it. you need to upload .html file. The file is added. you need to upload `.htm` file. Then i think my Question will be clear to you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Munni i trying to understand you requirement. whatever i understand i implements bellow code snippet. please check is it your requirement.

it will provide all links whatever html document you uploaded.

after running snippet kindly check result on console.

```js
function saveText(ref, fname, text, mime)
{
   var blob = new Blob([$('#result').text()], {type: "html/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, $('#fname').val() + '.html');
}

function fileValidation() {
 var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
 var filePath = fileInput.value;
 var allowedExtensions = /(\.html)$/i;
 if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {
     alert('Please upload file having extensions .html only.');
     fileInput.value = '';
     return false;
 }

 else {
     if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         var input = event.target;
         reader.onload = function(){
       let text = reader.result;
       document.getElementById('result').textContent = text;
     };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
     }
 }

}

function linkGenerate() {
    const result = document.getElementById('result'); //added
    const parser = new DOMParser(),// added
    dom = parser.parseFromString(result.innerText, "text/html"); //added
    let myDivContent = dom.querySelector('html'); // added
    let links = myDivContent.getElementsByTagName('a');
    console.log(links);
    for(let link of links)
 {
  let curhref = link.href;
  if(curhref.indexOf('http') > -1)
  {
      link.href = curhref.replace(/(\?|&)elqTrackId=[a-z0-9]+(&elqTrack=true)?/, '');
      if(link.href.indexOf('ea=') > -1)
      {
        link.href += '&utm_source=iconnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&emailId={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&codsId={{Account.CODS_External_Id__c}}&utm_term=';
      }
      else
      {
        link.href += '?utm_source=iconnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&emailId={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&codsId={{Account.CODS_External_Id__c}}&utm_term=';
      }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Zip</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS
  ==================== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom Stylesheet 
    ===================== -->
    <style>
    .form-control {
 display: inline-block !important;
 width: auto !important;  
}

#result {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Zip With Few Clicks</a>
    
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="linkGenerate()">Track ID Removal<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <form onsubmit="return saveText()" class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="saveblock" class="pull-right"> 
            <input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="filename" class="form-control"><span>.html</span>        
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" type="submit" role="button">Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </ul>

  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col">

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
          </div>
          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" onchange="return fileValidation()">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Output Div -->
        <div id="result" contenteditable="true"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="text-center bg-light pt-3 pb-2">
    <p>
      &copy;All rights reserved
    </p>
  </footer>

  <!-- jQuery CDN
    =============== -->
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/filesaver.js/0.2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom Script 
    ================ -->
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```